# Telegram bot receiving commands from other bot

Tags: telegram-bot

in the documentation of the telegram bot API I found:

> 3. Bots with privacy mode enabled will receive:
>
> Commands explicitly meant for them (e.g., /command@this_bot).
>
> General commands from users (e.g. /start) if the bot was the last bot
>   to send a message to the group.

So I created two bots - invited both in a group and had "firstbot" to fire /cmd@otherbot something commands. The "otherbot" echos everything it reads.

I (in the client) I can write - "otherbot" doesn't see it - which is correct due to privacy settings.
I i write /cmd@otherbot - "otherbot" receives and echos this - also correct.

BUT - when I let "firstbot" emit /cmd@otherbot in the group "otherbot" doesn't see it.
Am I doing something wrong - or am I miss-leaded by the documentation?

I use C# with Telegram.Bot by roundrobin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bots [can't see messages meant for other bots](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get), regardless of privacy modes.

> Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?
>
> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.

Comment: Thank you. I saw this before, but reading "commands directed directly" made me hope. Too bad - a simple "Hey friend check this out" would help a lot (at least in my scenario)

Comment: There is nothing stopping your bot from offering and out of band communication channel for direct communication between bots, so that'd be a perfectly fine use case for that.

Comment: That's what I wanted to overcome by using the secure telegram infrastructure. Else I could run my own signalR server or something like that. Scenario: botA only reachable by (selected)  humans and botaaB. It is capable of doing a number of critical things. BotB is public reachable and it forwards requests to botA or in special case to humans which (after checking) forward it to botA. Both bots are hehind a firewall only able to communicate with telegram using webhooks. Of course I could connect both bots via azure or so... But my hope was that it's possible to forward commands using telegram.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I came across with this problem, that one bot can't read messages from another bot.

But I've found a solution: instead of using the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), you can use [TDLib (Telegram Database library)](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/README.md) to read the messages.

I am using [python](https://github.com/alexander-akhmetov/python-telegram), so with this short piece of code I am able to read messages from a bot:

```
from telegram.client import Telegram

tg = Telegram(
    api_id=123456,
    api_hash='api_hash',
    phone='+555555555',
    database_encryption_key='changehere' )

tg.login()

def new_message_handler(update):
    message_content = update['message']['content']
    message_text = message_content.get('text', {}).get('text', '').lower()
    print(message_text)
    # do what you want with the message

tg.add_message_handler(new_message_handler)
tg.idle()
```

I guess that the same can be extended for other languages.

With this approach combined with Bot Telegram API, you are able to:

1. read messages from a bot (with Telegram Database library)
2. send that message with another bot (with Telegram Bot API)

Comment: have you tried your code by using one bot to send /cmd@otherbot which should fire the message handler on otherbot?

Comment: this code use user api instead of bot api