# The bot I wrote cannot read messages from the Telegram bot. (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

The bot I wrote in Node js takes the messages written by the users and assigns them to the value group. But I do not receive messages sent by another bot and send them to the other group.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const {log} = require("util");

app.use(cors());
const port = 2023;
const token = '******************';
const chatId  = '-100*********';
const sendChatId ='-100*************';

const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });


bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log("Start");
    console.log(msg);
    if (msg.chat.id.toString() === chatId) {
        
        if(msg.entities && msg.entities.length > 4){
            bot.sendPhoto(sendChatId, msg.entities[1].url, { caption: msg.text })
                .then((sentMessage) => {
                    console.log('Resimli mesaj gönderildi:', sentMessage.caption);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Resimli mesaj gönderme hatası:', error);
                });
        }else if(msg.photo && msg.photo.length >= 4){
            bot.sendPhoto(sendChatId, msg.photo[3].file_id, { caption: msg.caption })
            .then((sentMessage) => {
                console.log('Resimli mesaj gönderildi:', sentMessage.caption);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Resimli mesaj gönderme hatası:', error);
            });
        }
        else{
            bot.sendMessage(sendChatId, (msg.text && msg.text.length) > 0 ? msg.text : msg.caption)
                .then((sentMessage) => {
                    console.log('Metin mesajı gönderildi:', sentMessage.text);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Metin mesajı gönderme hatası:', error);
                });
        }
    }
    console.log("End");
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);



app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Success" });
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

All messages received in the group were read. However, it does not read messages from other bots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Telegram bot receiving commands from other bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016170/telegram-bot-receiving-commands-from-other-bot)

Comment: Telegram [doesn't allow that](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots).